# SLIMERJSLAUNCHER environment variable is missing. Set it with the path to Firefox or XulRunner

Tags: node.js, firefox, casperjs, xulrunner, slimerjs

everyone!

When I trying to run one test in casper:
`casperjs --engine=slimerjs test.js`

and got this msg

`SLIMERJSLAUNCHER environment variable is missing. Set it with the path to Firefox or XulRunner`

XulRunner, Firefox is installed. I'm using using Mac OS.

Comment: `export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox` doesn't helps

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. uninstall current slimerjs `brew uninstall slimerjs`
2. create a dir for git clone `mkdir ~/forked && cd $_`
3. clone slimerjs repo `git clone https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs.git`
4. export to path `export PATH=$PATH:~/forked/slimerjs/src`

**and next reboot terminal**, because for me it doesn't worked until I did a reboot.

Check this our by typing `slimerjs -v`

Happiness to everyone.